# insert multiple environment variables in curl json

Tags: php, json, unix, curl

```
TZ=EST5EDT date
update=XYZ

curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"XXXXX": "#XXXXXX", "username": "test for automation", "text":"'"$update"'","icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}' https://url
```

How do I insert both update andTZ as variable in the "text" key in the curl command?

Comment: I actually did store all the variables to a single variable and used in the curl command which worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did store all the variables to a single variable and used in the curl command which worked

```
TZ=EST5EDT date
Hello=XYZ
Update="$TZ","$Hello"

curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"XXXXX": "#XXXXXX", "username": "test for automation", "text":"'"$update"'","icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}' https://url
```